# Booting of RPi 3A+ fails for the Raspbian stretch 2018-03-13 and even for 2017-08-16

Tags: pi-3b+, sd-card, raspbian-stretch, kernel

I have a 16GB micro SD card, on which raspbian strecth 2018-03-13 is installed (via win32diskimager, earlier formatted via SD card formatter). It works perfectly for my RPi zero model, but doesn't work for my RPi3A+ model.
Though my RPI3A+ works perfectly for 2020-05-27 version of raspbian, but because that version doesn't support linux tool "perf", I am willing to use the older vesion which supports "perf".

How am I supposed to access the older version of raspbian stretch on my RPi3A+ model?
Or is there any way where the perf tool can be accessed / installed for the latest version (2020-05-27)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi3A was released on 15 Nov 2018.

Any OS older than this won't work, although you COULD try updating kernel and firmware from a later release.

NOTE **DO NOT** use `rpi-update` (at least without selecting a Stretch compatible release - which is not quite straightforward).

Running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` will install the latest supported kernel/bootcode, but this assumes you have a Pi that can boot - should be OK if run on the Pi Zero.

Comment: I inserted the SD card into RPi zero and ran the above 2 mentioned commands: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel . After that, I inserted back the card into my RPi 3A+, this time the green light did blink thankfully, but still I couldn't connect it to my laptop. What could be the possiblereason for that?

Comment: @SukhmaniKaurThethi **DO NOT** ask questions in Comments, update your question or ask a new Question. Unless you provide some details no one can say.